# What would be a good commit message for updating package versions using Conventional Commits?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, conventional-commits

Following [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0-beta.2/) what would be the best `<type>` for commits regarding package version changes (upgrades/updates)?

E.g.: `feat: Bump React version to "16.13.1"`

E.g.: `feat: Upgrade all dependencies`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Others: commit types other than fix: and feat: are allowed, for example @commitlint/config-conventional (based on the the Angular convention) recommends chore:, docs:, style:, refactor:, perf:, test:, and others. We also recommend improvement for commits that improve a current implementation without adding a new feature or fixing a bug. Notice these types are not mandated by the conventional commits specification, and have no implicit effect in semantic versioning (unless they include a BREAKING CHANGE, which is NOT recommended). A scope may be provided to a commit’s type, to provide additional contextual information and is contained within parenthesis, e.g., feat(parser): add ability to parse arrays.

Source: https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0-beta.2/

So an ideal candidate for me would be `chore: upgrade package dependencies` which must not result in any version number bump.

Be aware though that upgrading dependencies may or may not incur breaking changes which may result in a commit significantly bigger than just a `package.json` update.

But as far as your app goes, it would be your job to deal with those breaking changes without changing anything for the user. So in that respect I don't think that neither `feat:` nor `fix:` is justified as, *ideally*, this commit doesn't bring any user-facing changes.

Comment: But wouldn't you then have the same version number of your app while they each use different packages? Shouldn't there be a patch version bump?

Comment: Conventional Commits refers to the Angular project convention (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/22b96b9/CONTRIBUTING.md#type) and nowadays they don't use `chore` anymore. It seems the best aproach for this case is using `build`, like suggested in the not accepted answer.

Comment: I guess it depends what dependencies we're upgrading. The docs says: `Changes that affect the build system or external dependencies (example scopes: gulp, broccoli, npm)`.  External dependencies refer to libraries and tooling supporting the build system, not the application itself.

Comment: Had trouble interpretting that "external dependencies" as well. For reference, Github's dependabot likes to create these as: "build(deps): bump json from X to Y" for example

EDIT: Hmm it actually has both: "chore(deps): bump webpack..." and it seems to depend on which project I'm working in

Answer (score 43):

If you use `build` scope consider this option:

```
build(deps): bump React version to "17.0.2"
```

Conventional commits are based on the Angular conventional commits. Angular's [`CONTRIBUTING.md`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c88e87d/CONTRIBUTING.md#type) states:

> build: Changes that affect the build system or external dependencies (example scopes: gulp, broccoli, npm)

Comment: To be perfect, short summary should not be capitalized: `build(deps): bump react version to "17.0.2"`

Comment: @ebaynaud decapitalized