# Commit type when updating a git submodule (Conventional Commits)

Tags: commit, git-submodules

To respect the [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/) guide, what type (*fix, feat, chore, ...*) of commit should we use when it is related to an update of a git submodule ?

Best regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855111/what-would-be-a-good-commit-message-for-updating-package-versions-using-conventi

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a dependency update. I'd use `build` scope like so:

```
build(gitmodule): Update thing to a08fc4a (version 1.2.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using VS Code as your editor. You can use [Conventional Commits](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vivaxy.vscode-conventional-commits) extension to figure what kind of commit to use. Other than that I can also suggest you to look at this website [Conventional Commits Website](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/#summary)